# How to scan with Dell computer and HP 7410 printer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, scanner

I had Windows XP Professional and scanned well with my HP 7410.

I purchased a Dell computer with Windows 7 and Word 2000 but cannot figure out how to scan.

Comment: Your new Dell came with Word 2000? :)

Comment: I guess he means Word 2008.

Comment: Unless he has a verion of word that doesn't exist for Windows he probably means Word 2010

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Windows Fax and Scan](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Scan-a-document-or-photo-with-Windows-Fax-and-Scan) software included with Windows 7, which should be available in the main All Programs menu of your Start menu.

Alternatively, you can install HP's scanner software included on the CD or DVD that came with your printer or [available for download from HP's website](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?product=391194&lc=en).

Answer (score 0):

Every site I come across with this problem, says install the HP software. They are wrong it does not solve the problem.

The reality is that it does not work with Windows 7 when you press "scan to" on the printer. The software has a bug in it - works fine for XP but on 7 it won't.

A workaround is to scan from the computer using either software or go directly to the printer internal web address page using Internet Explorer.